# create a Batch file with a file path as an input argument

Tags: batch-file, console, cmd

I need to create a batch file which will run a program (which has been created in C#.Net) and also take a path of a text file as an input.

Not quite sure, how to achieve this.

So far, I have the below command working,

```
C:\>Folder Path to executable>xxxx.exe -console
```

-console is my predefined command argument to run this program in console mode.

The part until running the program from the console, with -console, works perfectly fine with a hard coded file path. However, I want to give the functionality to the user to give the file path as they want and create a batch file for the same command. Everytime user can update the batch file with new text file path and simply run it.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any reason not to use arguments for the .NET app itself, and skip the .bat?

Comment: @Jon of All Trades: No not at all, I just wanted to give a *.bat file so that user can run and forget about all other things. e.g. a developer can add it to their environment to run all the process automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just wanting to use the `-console` parameter?  Are there any other parameters you wanted to pass in?

If wanting just what you have in your snippet, Save the following into a batch file. (e.g. StartMyProgram.bat)

```
start "C:\Folder path to executable\xxxx.exe" -console
```

See `start /?` for help and more options.

Comment: thanks, this is what I needed. Already have implemented and worked fine.
I have updated my command with more arguments like -supress, this won't show messages during the process.
Nevertheless, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `%~1` to your script: `C:\Path\to\executable\xxxx.exe -console %~1`

Now you can call it like this: `StartMyApp.cmd C:\Docs\readme.txt`

`%~1` contains the full path of the text-file. You could also ensure that only text-files are passed to your application:

```
if "%~x1"==".txt" (
    C:\Path\to\executable\xxxx.exe -console %~1
) else (
    echo Not a textfile! & pause
)
```

Comment: this is perfect, however, I used it in other way.
The user will each time before running the *.bat will update the *.txt file path in it and then will run it to do all other process automatically.

Comment: It means, another developer will just need to add this *.bat in their code environment and while compiling, the process will happen in background without any more argument to pass.